# Dynamically accessing cells of table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a html page hierarchy like this , i want to access the elements in table ."akshay1234530@yahoo.com" & "ajdlkjalkdjaldkjlakdjla".

```html
<body> //in body

            <div id="page_content"> <!--access this div-->

                 <div id="page_settings_modal">

                 <div class="sqlqueryresults ajax"> <!-- then access this div-->

                          <div class="result_query" style="text-align: left">

                          <table class="navigation nospacing nopadding print_ignore">

                          <div class="common_hidden_inputs">

                          <form method="post" action="sql.php" name="displayOptionsForm" class="ajax print_ignore">

                          <form method="post" action="tbl_row_action.php" name="resultsForm"  class="ajax"> <!--access this form-->

                                   <div class="data" style="position: relative;"> <!-- access this div-->

                                             <table class="sticky_columns" style="position: fixed; z-index: 99; width: 568px; margin-left: 6.56px; top: 59px; display: none;">

                                             <table class="table_results ajax pma_table" data-uniqueid="24435"> <!--access this table-->

                                                   <tbody> <!--inside this tbody access the elements of tables in -->

                                                        <td data-decimals="0" data-type="string" data-originallength="23" class="data grid_edit click2 not_null   text ">
                                                                 <span>akshay1234530@yahoo.com</span>

                                                        </td>

                                                        <td data-decimals="0" data-type="blob" data-originallength="23" class="data grid_edit click2 not_null">
                                                                 <span>ajdlkjalkdjaldkjlakdjla</span>

                                                        </td>
```

I am not able figure out how to access the elements of table in this complex html page. Please help!!!!!!!

I have tried this so far

```
    var div1 = document.getElementById("page_content");  

    var div2=div1.getElementsByTagName("div")[1];

    var form1 = div2.getElementsByTagName("form")[2];

    var div3= form1.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

    var table1=div3.getElementsByTagName("table")[1];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Did you create this layout or is it something you have to work with and can't change? Is there a way to _not_ have a table inside a table inside a table? Otherwise it looks pretty straightforward to me, the table you want has a "table_results" class. You can start here and try something with that.

Comment: Actually this is a phpmyadmin page's html code. In this i have a table named email and i want access the elements of that  table.

Comment: Sooooo... what did you try? Do you know how to select a DOM element? If yes, it's easy, if not, there are zillions of tutorials out there.

Comment: var div1 = document.getElementById("page_content");
var div2=div1.getElementsByTagName("div")[1];
var form1 = div2.getElementsByTagName("form")[2];
var div3= form1.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var table1=div3.getElementsByTagName("table")[1];

Answer (score 0):

Following lines of code will return the value that u need

```
document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerText
document.getElementsByTagName("span")[1].innerText
```

1st - "akshay1234530@yahoo.com"
2nd - "ajdlkjalkdjaldkjlakdjla".